# To find posible order of $\frac {G}{Z (G)} $

Tags: group-theory

If $Z (G)$ denotes centre of group $G,$ the order of quotient group $\frac {G}{Z (G)} $
cannot be

$(A) 4.$

$(B)6.$

$(C)15.$

$(D)25.$

I know that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Any thoughts? Do you know some property that $G/Z(G)$ cannot have?

Comment: I know if G/Z (G) is cyclic then G is abelian

Comment: No no - $G$ is abelian! The center $Z(G)$ is *always* abelian.

Comment: @user1729 Yes typo ,

Comment: Can you check whether a group with order as given in A, B, C, D will be cyclic always?

Comment: @kYes by sylow theory theorems

Comment: @Krish C is cyclic

Comment: Check for each of the cases A, B, C, D to see if any of these orders implies the corresponding group is cyclic. That will give you the answer in light of your comment above. As you mentioned, for C it will be cyclic always. So C is one answer. Is it the only answer?

Comment: @Krish It is not quite enough to check if the numbers are cyclic. You need to find examples with quotients of those orders to show they can happen.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: You are right. That's why I asked *"Is it the only answer?"*. I didn't say that it is the only answer.

Comment: @Krish Right, but your comment seemed to suggest that finding if the numbers were cyclic would suffice.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Sorry for that. English is not my first language, so sometimes I may be sounded little unclear. Thanks for pointing out a potential confusing issue.

Comment: @Krish BTW, you might be interested in the chat room for finite group theory http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19567/finite-group-theory (still trying to get people to use it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments the OP states that he knows that "if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ must be abelian". This is the key idea. The secondary idea is: when is a group of order $pq$ or $p^2$ cyclic, for $p$ and $q$ primes?

- If $p$ and $q$ are non-equal then it is related to $p$ dividing
  $q-1$, but I presume that this will have already been covered as it
  requires a lot of work otherwise, so this would be an odd question!
- For the $p^2$ case then think about $\mathbb{Z_p}\times\mathbb{Z_p}$.

So, if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then what must is actually be? Can it be, for example, cyclic of order $7$? what about $21?$ No! What must it be?

Then go through the list working out which orders can only give you cyclic groups, using your prior knowledge about groups of order $pq$ and of order $p^2$.

As has been pointed out in the comments by @Tobias, you then need to prove that for each of the remaining three orders $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ there exists a group $G_i$ such that $G_i/Z(G_i)$ has order $x_i$. For example, there exists a non-abelian group of order $8$, so $G/Z(G)$ has order $4$ (why?).

Comment: I am not getting .

Comment: @godonichia If $G$ is abelian, what is the order of $G/Z(G)$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft i guess 1 .no i know 1

Comment: @godonichia Yes, exactly. But don't guess it - *know* it! If $G$ is abelian than $Z(G)=G$ so $G/Z(G)$ is trivial. This means that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then is must actually be trivial (and not cyclic of order $7$ or $21$.

Comment: Ok i see now thanks

Comment: I donot understand why it can be 4

Comment: @godonichia There are two groups of order $4$, and only one is cyclic.

Comment: Can you give an idea about why by option d is wrong

Comment: @godonichia Same reason as with option $A$: there are two groups of order $p^2$, $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ and $\mathbb{Z_p\times Z_p}$. Only one of these is cyclic.

Comment: So for other orders i need  to show existence of non cyclic group

Comment: @godonichia Exactly.

Comment: @godonichia Not only that. You need to find an example of a group $G$ such that $G/Z(G)$ has the given order.

Comment: For 6 order $S_3$ WILL DO

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft can you suggest a way

Comment: @godonichia For order $6$, try to find a group of order $12$ with center of order $2$ (this should be an example you are familiar with).

Comment: @godonichia For the $p^2$ examples ($25$ and $8$) find a non-abelian group of order $p^3$.

Answer (score 5):

If $H=(G/Z(G))$
then say if $o(H)=15$

then $H$ will have  a unique  sylow 3 subgroup and a  unique sylow 5 subgroup ;hence by the internal direct property of groups $H\cong \mathbb Z_3\times \mathbb Z_5$ and $gcd(3,5)=1$
 will imply $H\cong \mathbb Z_{15}$

Thus $H$ is cyclic .If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then G is abelian and hence $G=Z(G)$ contradicting our assumption

Thus C will be never true

Comment: @godonichia: In this answer it is beautifully explained that (C) is never true. But you should check whether there are other possibilities or not, i.e. whether it is the only case which is never true or there are other cases also.

Comment: @Krish other options wont work out

Comment: Then you are done (I was saying to check for all the options just to be sure). Cheers!!

Comment: @Krish i meant how do i check for other options

Comment: @godonichia: For (A), consider the quaternion group. For (B), consider $S_3$ or dihedral group of order 12. For (D), you need to consider non-abelian group of order 125 (note that in this case the center will be non-trivial always). There are only two non-isomorphic non-abelian group of order 125.